# Want a UISegmentedControl enabled to be selected

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm looking for a way to **disable** a segmented control (5 segments, represent a "progress bar") to be selected, as I'm using it to display the rate of a parameter.

Is there a simple way to do that ?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to enable individual segments within the control?

Comment: F*** I'm sorry it's disable ! I'm editing ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[self.segmentedControl setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Post edited, it's disable my all segments to be selected, sorry

Comment: @Hetana This post is the correct answer. And if you want to disable the segment, all you have to do is change the `YES` to `NO` in the above code. Additionally, `forSegmentAtIndex` specifies which segment to disable from left to right. So if you have three segments, their indexes would be 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: Ok That works but it adds a with translucent filter on my images. Can I get rid of it ?

Comment: @Hetana That is by design. This way your user is given a visual hint that the button is disabled before they try to tap it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set it simply: `mySegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 3;`

Comment: Post edited, it's disable my all segments to be selected, sorry